# uRapidFlow: How to update tax_class_id attribute on products being store view specific

Tags: magento-enterprise

Title explains pretty well my issue.

Does any one knows how to achieve this with uRapidFlow?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you contacted extension support about this?

Answer (score 1):

Tax class id is website scope attribute and unless you have changed that, you can only set it per website not per store view.
Other than that you should provide tax name e.g. None to set correct tax id.

Comment: And it is not a good idea to change the scope of the attribute. Won't work like you hope, OP.